# Dynamically loading style in Flex AIR App

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, air, stylesheet

So i decided to implement some themes in my AIR app. I have converted my CSS files into SWF files, removed the Style linkage from my main file. Based on the user preferences stored in a file, I decide which theme to use. i.e; load the SWF file using `StyleManager` class.

I made my application window invisible, added a `StyleEvent.COMPLETE` event listener for the `IEventDispatcher` object returned by `StyleManager.loadStyleDeclarations` method. After the `StyleEvent.COMPLETE` occurs, I made my main window visible.

The problem i have now is, for a few seconds, i can see white canvases and all my components without any styles before using the style selected. I want to know if my approach is correct or do I need to make any changes to implement this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I seem to have figured it out myself. Getting some help from this [link](http://askmeflash.com/tutorial/2/how-to-load-dynamic-stylesheet-before-application-shows) albeit.

Previously i read the settings in my `applicationComplete` and loaded the styles. So i guess all the UI components were created and added to the display list. They were bare naked without any style values.

So i changed the reading of the settings file to `preinitialize`, so that by the time the `applicationComplete` is triggered, AIR has already loaded the SWF stylesheet. So it will display the UI as i wanted.

Comment: Can you tell me the difference for writing things in `preinitialize` and `initialize`? i've only used `creationComplete` and `applicationComplete` till now.

Comment: Off hand: We dont use preinitialize, as not all children of a container/object will have been created. We always use 'initialize' for setting variables, supplying dataProvider collections with data (as Adobe recommend). All a containers children have been created at this point. All our eventlisteners get set in creationComplete (as Adobe recommend), which gets fired after all its children, and children's children are created and visible.

Comment: I have only read from a settings file, loaded the style sheet into memory in my `preinitialize` code. Any UI related things i did in `applicationComplete`.

Comment: ha ha, i had to use `applicationComplete` as i had to set up listeners to `Application.application.stage`. Was getting a null exception when i tried to put that in `creationComplete`